# Shopping Cart Rules based on if a row total ends in specific amount

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

I would like to implement a shopping cart rule in magento that allows me to check If a product has a price that ends in a specific number. For example, if a row total is something of the form XX.50, then I want to apply free shipping to the entire cart. So, the rule would be something like:

```
if row total *contains*: 0.50
```

Then apply free shipping to the cart. it doesn't seem like this is working for me, even after estimating shipping rates and clicking "get a quote". I do not want the customer to use a coupon code, I want this discount to be applied automatically when proceeding to checkout. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know from the top of my head if the condition you want is available, but there is a free shipping action. This action however, sets the cost for the shipping method to zero, it doesn't disable the shipping methods, as customer should still be able to pick the carrier of her choice. If a shipping method still shows the "get a quote" button, when the rule is active, complain with the developer of the extension.

Answer (score 2):

The Shopping cart price rules conditions have a `contains` option. That should check for part of the string in the database

[image]